# Mysql: get result from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables.

Phonebook:

```
 _________________________________
| id | Photo   | Name | Number    |
|---------------------------------|
| 1  | abc.jpg | John | 123-45-67 |
|---------------------------------|
| 2  | def.jpg | Sam  | 482-34-00 |
|_________________________________|
```

History:

```
 ____________________________________
| id  | Name | Date       | Type     |
|------------------------------------|
| 24  | John | 17.03.2014 | Incoming |
|------------------------------------|
| 25  | Sam  | 18.03.2014 | Incoming |
|------------------------------------|
| 26  | Sam  | 19.03.2014 | Outgoing |
|____________________________________|
```

I need to get all columns from `History` table where id = `$id` (25 in my case) and get `Image` column from `Phoneboock` where `History.Name = Phonebook.Name` (Sam in my case). Below is the result that I want to get:

```
 ______________________________________________
| id  | Name | Date       | Type     | Image   |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 25  | Sam  | 18.03.2014 | Incoming | def.jpg |
|______________________________________________|
```

Comment: Everything is you know and it is simple so what you want ?

Comment: Whats your question exactly? It seems like you already know what are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is the SQL to get your data, so use this:

```
SELECT History.*, Phonebook.Photo
FROM History INNER JOIN Phonebook ON Phonebook.Name = History.Name 
AND History.id = $id
```

Comment: @Julie Redfoot
Which one of your options is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the SQL Select statement, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT HISTORY.*, PHONEBOOK.Photo FROM HISTORY, PHONEBOOK
WHERE HISTORY.Name = PHONEBOOK.Name AND HISTORY.id='25'
```

Comment: @sal00m 
Which one of your options is better to use?

Comment: There's no difference between using `inner join` or not (afaik), both has the same explain plan. So both are correct :)

Comment: I agree with sal00m. There is really no difference. You'll get the same outcome with the tables you provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM History INNER JOIN Phonebook WHERE  History.name = Phonebook.name
```

That will give you a join of all the rows. You can customize it more to get what you want. Look at `JOIN` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for more info